# ESLint false positive error prettier/prettier after upgrading packgaes

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

I have deleted the yarn.lock and node_modules folder and then ran yarn install to generate a new yarn.lock file. Everything was working just fine until now. However, ESLint is throwing a false positive error.

[Eslint error in my terminal when i run the linter command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YABLv.png)

I suspect there is a conflict between the packages because all of them have a caret (^) symbol in their version, which automatically updates them to the latest minor version when i run yarn install. Before I deleted the yarn.lock file, they were at the exact versions as shown below in my package.json file:

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
        "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.0.9",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.1",
        "eslint": "^7.13.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.10",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.1",
        "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^2.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4"
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "next": "13.1.6",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        ...
    },
```

and Here is my .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "next/core-web-vitals",
        "plugin:mdx/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
        "react/display-name": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "import/export": 0,
        "@next/next/no-img-element": ["error"],
        "import/no-anonymous-default-export": ["error"]
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
            "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
            "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
            "extends": [
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
            ],
            "rules": {
                "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "args": "none" }]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I suggest not using `^`. Instead, use `~` as it will keep to versions close to the original. This requires you to be more mindful about upgrades, which is a good thing as you might be finding out right now. If you want to be super strict you can use `=`.